# tableViewSelectionDidChange does not work in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After upgrading to MacOS Sierra, and consequently for Xcode 8, the `tableViewSelectionDidChange` function does not work anymore. I think my code is correct.

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {

if let selectedRow = (notification.object as AnyObject).selectedRow {
    if ( selectedRow > -1 ) {
        selectedItem = data[selectedRow]
        if let nome = selectedItem?.value(forKey: "nome") as? String {
            nomeField.stringValue = nome
        } else {
            blankOutField(nomeField)
        }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate
    managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    fetchDataAndRefreshTable()
}

func fetchDataAndRefreshTable() {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName: "CadastroPacientes")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nome", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    do {
        data = try managedContext!.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch {
        Swift.print(error)
    }  
}
```

I cannot find the solution because it seems that the line is not selected, nothing happens when I click the line in the TableView.

The program is using Core Data. Everything worked perfectly before.

Comment: Check your brackets because I'm not sure that the viewDidLoad is supposed to be in this `func tableViewSelection` function. It looks like it's missing a closing bracket before the beginning of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: in fact, the viewDidLoad is a separate function. The code is correct. The idea was to paste the three functions involved.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! Change the binary operator solved my problem !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Change `selectedRow > -1` to `selectedRow >= -1` because `Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type Int`.... NEXT If you can change `selectedItem` to `selectedRow` Those are the main errors that I get when I try and run your code